# codeigniter count_all_results with join table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem getting the number of rows from my tables.

Here is my mysql query using codeiginiter:

```
$this->db->where('rd', 1);
$this->db->where('id_user_first', $user_type);
$this->db->from("messaging");
$this->db->join('answers', "answers.id_message = messaging.id AND answers.id_user != '$user_type'");
$count_reponse  = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

I get this error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' ''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in

Comment: `$user_type` what value get in this variable?

Comment: I recommend to remove '' from $user_type

Comment: @PankajMakwana Is an INT value of any users.

Comment: @RahulMeshram The problem is not there sir, and i prefer to use them especially for long value or encrypted entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solution for your problem :

> Please changes query

```
$this->db->select('messaging.*, answers.*');
$this->db->from("messaging");
$this->db->join('answers', "answers.id_message = messaging.id");
$this->db->where('answers.id_user <>', $user_type);
$this->db->where('messaging.rd', 1);
$this->db->where('messaging.id_user_first', $user_type);
$count_reponse  = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but still getting the exact same error message.

Comment: Please post new error message and please check now new answer.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your quotes or change the inner double-quotes to single quotes.

```
$this->db->join('answers', 'answers.id_message = messaging.id AND answers.id_user != '.$user_type.'','left');
```

Try This query:

```
$this->db->where('rd', 1);
$this->db->where('id_user_first', $user_type);
$this->db->from("messaging");       
$this->db->join('answers', 'answers.id_message = messaging.id', 'left');        
$this->db->where('answers.id_user !=', $user_type);
$count_reponse  = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

I hope it will help. Please leave a comment if any error came.